# OSL script includes and reuse

Tags: scripting, osl

Is it possible to include one OSL file in another so I can use the functions from it or must I copy and paste everything every time I want to reuse it?

OSL seems to have #include functionality, but is there a way to use it for script files within Blender?

(I'm using internal script files, but I can change if that helps.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimentation, it appears that #include-ing OSL files works with external scripts, but not internal.

The OSL compiler takes a shader file as input, and seems to use the directory of that file as a base for further includes. It also looks in the `\scripts\addons\cycles\shader` directory.

If external scripts are used, the OSL compiler therefore looks in the correct directory, and will find included files correctly.

If internal scripts are used, the script being compiled is moved by itself to a temporary directory, given a random name, and deleted afterwards. This means that internal scripts cannot use #includes unless the included files are placed in the `\scripts\addons\cycles\shader` directory.